# Compress folder following any symbolic links

Tags: ftp, symbolic-link, tar, compression, gzip

I store a lot of my data in a flat structure and the create symbolic links to different folders where my clients can access them via OwnCloud.

I need to compress one of these folders containing sym-links and send it to a client via ftp, but I simply cannot get my compressors to follow my symbolic links.

e.g. Create file `data.tar` from folder `/data`, where `/data/a.txt` is a sym-link to `/home/data/a.txt`, thus I need `/home/data/a.txt` to be the file that's compressed into `data.tar`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the manual for `tar` includes an option for this:

```
-h, --dereference
don't archive symlinks; archive the files they point to
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue seems to have been when using `tar`, my order of params were wrong:

This is the correct example:

```
tar -h -cf data.tar /data/a.txt
```